# Play RTMP live stream in HTML5

Tags: audio, mp3, rtmp, ogg

I have one user streaming microphone in RTMP from a Flash app.
How can I broadcast this stream to other users using HTML5 (no Flash)?

Do browsers support live audio streaming in HTML5?
What format do I need to use, mp3, ogg?

Thanks

Comment: There's no one universal streaming format for video or audio. the W3C specified the audio/video tags, but chickened out in backing any standard codecs. You'll have to stream different formats for each browser.

Comment: Can I listen to live mic audio stream with the HTML5 audio tag assuming I will transcode it to the correct format?

Comment: @pablo : It can also be done with [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/streams-api/).

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 does NOT support RTMP. They do however support audio playback, using the  tag. You need to include mp3 ogg and wav, as no one format is supported by all browsers. However, like I said, HTML5 only supports httpd, not RTMP

Comment: In my question I asked what format do I need to use because I know that HTML5 doesn't support RTMP. I also interested in live stream and not streaming from a file.

Comment: As I said, you need to use mp3, wav and ogg for complete browser compatibility

Comment: I'm asking about LIVE streaming.

Comment: And I also told you that HTML5 ONLY supports HTTP, not RTMP. There's no way to live stream audio using HTML5 and not Flash

Comment: @GarethParker : Maybe It [will change](http://www.w3.org/2012/sysapps/tcp-udp-sockets/) in the future...

Answer (score 2):

It seems HTML5 now supports file streaming, but I don't think it's compatible with RTMP. Here's a link though

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the audience. WebRTC will be a good choice if you have 1-8 audiences at maximum.

If you want to distribute this video to a large audience, you should use RTMP protocol. I suggest that to use an encoder app to send your video stream to your server. OBS Studio will be great for this job.

If you have to get the video stream from the browser, then the structure becomes more complex.
I have used a Selective Forwarding Unit(SFU) server to manage real-time streams between users. Then created a puppet, which acts as an audience but no one sees it. I've sent a collective video stream to my RTMP server and then distributed it.

You can distribute your video over HLS, FLV, or websockets. My suggestion is to use Videojs package to manage video flow. There is HLS and FLV support for RTMP distributions.